# How to make a button inside a gridview cause a partial post back and update my panel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

Code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Button lb = e.Row.FindControl("out") as Button;
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lb);
    }
}
```

Button:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" Visible="True">     
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button Visible='<%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Signout_Time").ToString()) %>' ID="out" runat="server" Text="Sign out" CommandName="SignOut" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("SN") %>' ClientIDMode="AutoID"/>                                
    </ItemTemplate>    
</asp:TemplateField>
```

UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="update1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="out" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I have an update panel with a gridview. The gridview consists of a button column. I want everytime this button is clicked, the update panel should be refreshed. From what I have been able to achieve, the button works fine but I would only be able to see the effect when i refreshed the whole page again. I need to see the effect on the click event without refreshing the page. How do I make this gridview button cause partial postback

Comment: Please post update panel markup too. Is the button inside the update panel?

Comment: the button is inside the gridview column all placed in the Update panel. I tried ujsing AsynPostback Control id="out" but i got an error saying control id out cannot be found

Comment: "Please post update panel markup too" - please do